# Laravel 5 testing undefined property $client

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5

I'm giving Laravel 5 (4.3) a go and have tried writing some simple controller tests like so:

```
public function testIndex()
{
   $this->call('GET', 'posts');

   $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

When I run the test I get an error:

> ErrorException: Undefined property: PostsControllerTest::$client

Why has the client attribute disappeared from the test class in Laravel 5?

Comment: Laravel 5 isn't even in beta. Expect things to break at random.

Answer (score 1):

Functions like

```
$this->assertResponseOk();
```

are not available in the current build of Laravel 5. I'm not sure if Taylor plans to reintroduce them.

I think you can add the following package to get back some of the functionality

```
https://github.com/orchestral/testbench
```

Comment: As an update - these appear to be back in Laravel 5 in the latest alpha build